# Simple way to get the first non whitespace character from string

Tags: bash

The first non whitespace character is `a` in    `abc`,i get it with:

```
echo '   abc' | grep -o '^\s\+.' |tr -d  ' '
a
```

Is there more shorter way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's shorten your own command first by removing useless spaces and using a here string instead of `echo` and a pipe. Let's also make it string independent with a bash variable:

```
s='   abc'
grep -o '^\s\+.'<<<$s|tr -d  ' '
```

It is now 32 characters long. Can we find shorter? Yes, with `tr` and `cut`. If the whitespaces are real spaces (not tabs) here is a 22 characters long script:

```
tr -d ' '<<<$s|cut -c1
```

If the whitespaces can also be tabs we need two more characters, that is, 24:

```
tr -d ' \t'<<<$s|cut -c1
```

If they can be any horizontal whitespace we need 6 more (30):

```
tr -d '[:blank:]'<<<$s|cut -c1
```

And if they can be any horizontal or vertical whitespace (but if the string contains newlines your `grep`-based solution does not work any more), we still have a 30 characters long script:

```
tr -d '[:space:]'<<<$s|cut -c1
```

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving a regex match from the `BASH_REMATCH[]` array:

```
str='   abc'
regex='[^[:space:]]'                                          # match a single non-whitespace character
[[ "${str}" =~ ${regex} ]] && char1="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
```

Result:

```
$ typeset -p char1
declare -- char1="a"

$ echo "${char1}"
a
```

**NOTE:** while this requires a bit more typing it has the benefit of eliminating the performance overhead of creating a subshell for each piped command (eg, `| grep`, `|tr` , `| awk`, `| sed`, `| cut`)

---

Another idea using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to strip out whitespace characters plus a substring call:

```
str='   abc'
newstr="${str//[[:space:]]/}"                 # strip out whitespace
char1="${newstr:0:1}"                         # extract 1st character via substring (start position 0, length of 1)
```

Result:

```
$ typeset -p char1
declare -- char1="a"

$ echo "${char1}"
a
```

**NOTE:** a little less typing and this also eliminates the performance overhead of creating a subshell for each piped command (eg, `| grep`, `|tr` , `| awk`, `| sed`, `| cut`)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '   abc  sd ggf ' | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c 1
echo '   abc  sd ggf ' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | cut -d' ' -f 1 | cut -c 1
echo '   abc  sd ggf ' | sed -r 's/\s+//' | cut -c -1
```

PS: Corrected for printing the first character.

Comment: That prints `abc`, but the question is asking for it to print `a`. I think you want `cut -c1` for that?

Comment: Yes, misunderstood the question. Will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with just parameter expansion forms:

```bash
shopt -s extglob # Turn on extended globs to get +()
foo='   abc'
trimmed=${foo##+([[:space:]])} # Remove leading whitespace if any
echo "${trimmed:0:1}" # And display the first character of the remaining text
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE 1` ::: ***MUCH*** cleaner

```
mawk '_ {exit} _ = _$(NF = 1)' RS='[ \t-\r]+' FS=
```

It assigns the 1st character into `_`, so as long as the input rows are empty, it wouldn't exit.

The `_$( )` isn't anything special - it's merely a straight up string concat of variable `_` with field `$( … )`

> 

```
echo '   abc' |
```

---

```
gawk '_ {exit} _ = "" < $(NF=1)' RS='[ \t-\r]+' FS=
```

---

```
a
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Comment: @Itération122442 : i realized how inefficient my code was -thanks for the heads up